# error when using tikzpicture with moodle package

Tags: pdftex, shell-escape

I want to generate a quiz for my students to be imported within the *moodle* platform . The quiz includes some figure.

I  tried the *moodle* package from texlive 2018 but I get the following error when using the *tikzpicture* environment  :

```
ERROR:
Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "geometry-tikztemp-1" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{geometry}\input{geometry}"' did NOT result in a usable output file 'geometry-tikztemp-1' (expected one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:).

Please verify that you have enabled system calls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -shell-escape'. Sometimes it is also named 'write 18' or something like that.

Or maybe the command simply failed? Error messages can be found in 'geometry-tikztemp-1.log'. 

If you continue now, I'll try to typeset the picture.
```

Here is an example:

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage[draft]{moodle}
 \begin{document}
  \begin{quiz}{geometry}
    \begin{multi}{circle}
      is the shape in the figure a circle?

      \begin{tikzpicture}
       \draw (0,0)circle[radius=1cm];
      \end{tikzpicture}

      \item yes
      \item* no
    \end{multi}

  \end{quiz}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an answer but a workaround if you are in a rush. To be honest, I have hardly ever seen as strong "side-effects" as I see here with `moodle`. Even trying to do the `\savebox` after loading this package fails. Hope you find an expert who can fix this.

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage[draft]{moodle}
 \newsavebox\picbox
\begin{lrbox}{\picbox}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
       \draw (0,0) circle(1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{lrbox}
 \begin{document}
  \begin{quiz}{geometry}
    \begin{multi}{circle}
      is the shape in the figure a circle?

\usebox\picbox

      \item yes
      \item* no
    \end{multi}

  \end{quiz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: fwiw the error in the original is that `\pgfexternal@originalshipout` is said to be undefined (at end of expansion of `\pgf@externalend`. And I see in `moodle.sty` near end of file that it does rather heavy patching of Tikz, with a `\renewenvironment{tikzpicture}` at begin document. Thus the issue might need reporting to `moodle.sty` author.

Comment: @jfbu Thanks! Yes, that makes sense, and seems to explain the "side-effects". (If I was the OP, I would consider switching to another package.)

Comment: @marmot, is someone aware of another package that helps creating quiz in moodle ?

Comment: @HafidBoukhoulda Someone: probably yes, but unfortunately not me. But you could ask a question, I would also be interested in the result, and asking questions is free.

Comment: I did a search on ctan with the keyword *moodle* but without any success!

Comment: @HafidBoukhoulda Between us: this seems to be a bit a dangerous package. Why is it necessary for a package whose purpose is to typeset quizzes to (a) force you to externalize `tikzpicture`s and, what is IMHO even worse, (b) to do `\renewenvironment{tikzpicture} `? To me this does not make sense, but of course I cannot rule out that there might be reasons for it. Nor did I verify the findings of jfbu but I fully trust this user, who has a very good reputation (which is not reflected by the score).

Answer (score 2):

As `moodle` manual says, it invokes `\usetikzlibrary{external}`, therefore calling `--shell-escape` option in compilation process is a  must and then you will get the following picture.

[image]

Comment: to compile I have tried the following `pdflatex --shell-escape geometry.tex`  and `pdflatex -shell-escape geometry.tex` but without any success (the same error)

Comment: I've never gotten externalize to work, either.  Try using `\tikzexternaldisable`.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I did (very often) get externalize to work and of course the first thing I tried is to compile with `-shell-escape`. IMHO `moodle` introduces complications beyond that, which is why I only offered a workaround. I am actually wondering if this answer works for you or anyone else, at least for the OP and me it does not seem to work.

Comment: @HafidBoukhoulda
I've tried both of `pdflatex` and `xelatex` engine with `--shell-escape`, getting the same results.

`pdflatex` and `xelatex` versions of my `TeX` distro. are: 
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018)
XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.99999 (TeX Live 2018)

I also updated the picture because I'd erased one line in your file and it produced an award result.

Comment: If @javadr has got a result can we conclude that the issue is not with the moodle package? and what should we investigate further to  eliminate the error? 
Me too I use pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018) !

Comment: externalization in itself works fine for me, but the moodle example not, so it broke something, let the author debug this.

Comment: I'm so confused, why does it work on my PC without any problems? I use TeXLive2018 on Linux (Fedora). Did anyone of you try it on Linux or it was just me?!

Answer (score 2):

This answer comes a long time after the question but it might help someone to know that:

1. the example provided by the OP compiles fine if the package `tikz` is loaded after `moodle` (version `0.5`).
2. starting from version `0.8` of the `moodle` package, you no longer need to load `tikz` after `moodle`.