# Issue with the frame on the first page with package the moodle in LuaLaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, luatex, moodle

I'm trying to add a frame using Tikz.

My example doesn't work at this location:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \draw[line width=0.5mm] 
    ($(current page.north west) + (20mm, -10mm)$)
    rectangle
    ($(current page.south east) + (-10mm, 10mm)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Compilation Options in TeXStudio:

```
lualatex.exe -shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

How to add a frame without Tikz or how to fix it?

MWE:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
%==========================================================
\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
%==========================================================
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
%==========================================================
\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=modern]{russian}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setmonofont{Courier New}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfonttt[Script=Cyrillic]{Courier New}[Scale=0.976]
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{Times New Roman}[Scale=0.976]
\setsansfont{Arial}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfontsf{Arial}[Scale=0.976]
\linespread{0.976}
%==========================================================
\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}
\microtypecontext{kerning=russian}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=25mm, right=15mm, top=20mm, bottom=20mm, headsep=0pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, decorations.pathmorphing}
%==========================================================
\usepackage[section]{moodle}
\moodleset{ppi=100}
%==========================================================
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \draw[line width=0.5mm] 
    ($(current page.north west) + (20mm, -10mm)$)
    rectangle
    ($(current page.south east) + (-10mm, 10mm)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
~\vfill
\centerline{Title}
~\vfill
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\begin{quiz}{Section-1}
    \begin{numerical}[points=2]{Basic addition}
        What is $8+3$?
        \item 11
    \end{numerical}
\end{quiz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Place `\tikzset{external/export next=false}` immediately before the `tikzpicture` environment. The `moodle` packages loads the `external` library for Ti*k*Z, but this seems to conflict with `overlay` and `current page` nodes. Hence, you need to temporarily disable externalization. Sorry, I closed this too quickly ... After reopening, I will post a proper answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `moodle` package loads the `external` library for Ti*k*Z. Therefore, Ti*k*Z will try to externalize all `tikzpicture`s in your document. This can lead to problems, expecially (but not only) for `tikzpicture`s that use `overlay` and `current page` nodes. Also see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/459835/47927).

You can disable externalization temporarily by adding `\tikzset{external/export next=false}` before the `tikzpicture` in question:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[section]{moodle}
\moodleset{ppi=100}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{external/export next=false}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \draw[line width=0.5mm] 
    ([shift={(20mm, -10mm)}]current page.north west)
    rectangle
    ([shift={(-10mm, 10mm)}]current page.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
~\vfill
\centerline{Title}
~\vfill
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\begin{quiz}{Section-1}
    \begin{numerical}[points=2]{Basic addition}
        What is $8+3$?
        \item 11
    \end{numerical}
\end{quiz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help, Jasper Habicht!

Comment: @Youra_P I still don't completely understand where the problem sits. In the [other thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/459835/47927) they say that such issues should be solved in recent versions of the `moodle` package, but obviously not for every use case. Be it as it may, since the issues eventually stem from externalisation (which is not trivial to set up anyways), disabling it temporarily is probably really the best way to solve this.